# How to refresh selected item In paging library

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging, android-paging-library

I am using the android paging library to show a list of posts in the recycler view, my data source loads data from inMemory list which I add and remove from it then invalidate the data source to refresh the PagedListAdapter, everything is working well, but the problem is that when I scroll through pages, for example, page #5, and delete some item and call invalidate(), the data source will be re-initialized and will invoke the callbacks again, which re-loads the items in the recycler view, and jump to the first page.
The question is: How to refresh the items without jumping to the first page, and stick in the selected position?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's better to share your code. Maybe you forgot something or you mistaken somewhere :) . Please check this doc maybe it will help you : https://medium.com/@sharmadhiraj.np/android-paging-library-step-by-step-implementation-guide-75417753d9b9

Comment: invalidate will redraw all items in the list, when removing item use notifyItemRemoved() method

Comment: thanks, it is working :)